# Overlapping labels in heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, heatmaply

I am making an heatmap with "heatmaply" R package, but I have overlapping rownames (see red circled area).
Any suggestion or tutorial about fixing this problem?

Thanks a lot! [image]

Comment: It looks like you have about 100 different labels on the y axis. This is unlikely to make for a clear plot whatever you do. Your labels will not clash if you make the plotting area much bigger, but I think you would need either a very large plot (over 2000 pixels) to see the names. From a data visualisation point-of-view, the best thing might be to turn this into a number of smaller plots, perhaps grouping the y axis variables into clusters and having a plot for each cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fontsize_row` argument to set it to a number smaller than 10.

E.g.:

```
library("heatmaply")
heatmaply(mtcars) # default fontsize_row is 10
```

[image]

```
library("heatmaply")
heatmaply(mtcars, fontsize_row = 5)
```

[image]